# How to return correct values for listview using WCF?

Tags: c#, listview, wcf

I want to populate listview with information retrieved from database using WCF in C# and am not able to retrieve correct data for listview binding.

```
  public interface IServicePl
    {

        [OperationContract]
 [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<InterventiiCuEchipament> GetInterventiiCuEchipaments();
        
        
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class InterventiiCuEchipament
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string EchipamentInterventie { get; set; }
        public int id_interventie { get; set; }
        public string tip_interventie { get; set; }
        public string responsabil { get; set; }
        public DateTime data_finalizare { get; set; }
        public bool status { get; set; }
    }
```

```
       public IEnumerable<InterventiiCuEchipament> GetInterventiiCuEchipaments()
        {
               try
                {
                IEnumerable<InterventiiCuEchipament> query =  from sel1 in dataP.interventiis
                            join sel2 in dataP.sesizaris
                            on sel1.id_interventie equals sel2.id_sesizare
                            select new InterventiiCuEchipament()
                            {
                                id_interventie = sel1.id_interventie,
                                EchipamentInterventie = sel2.echipament,
                                tip_interventie = sel2.tip_sesizare,
                                responsabil = sel1.responsabil,
                                data_finalizare = (DateTime)sel1.data_finalizare,
                                status = (bool)sel1.status

                            };
                    return query;
                }
```

On the client side I have the following code :

```
 if (client.InnerChannel.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    {
                        List<InterventiiCuEchipament> ListaInterventii = new List<InterventiiCuEchipament>();
                         ListaInterventii = client.GetInterventiiCuEchipamentsAsync().Result.ToList();
                            InterventiiList.ItemsSource = ListaInterventii;
                        InterventiiList.Items.Refresh();
                            }
```

Output from query is ok, like in this image

[image: query output]
Output for listview binding is like in this image

[image: Listview output]

Why I can see just the count of query? and not correct values returned by query.

Answer (score 0):

If the query returns values, then ListaInterventii should also have values.
I wrote a similar demo, you can compare it.

You can use foreach to see if there is a value.

```
 ListaInterventii = client.GetInterventiiCuEchipamentsAsync().Result.ToList();
            foreach(var a in ListaInterventii)
            {
                int A = a.id_interventie;
            }
```

---

**Demo**

```
public class ProductService : IServicePl
    {   
        public IEnumerable<InterventiiCuEchipament> GetInterventiiCuEchipaments()
        {
            // This comes from database.
            var _dbCountries = new List<InterventiiCuEchipament>
        {
            new InterventiiCuEchipament {id_interventie = 1, tip_interventie="1"},
            new InterventiiCuEchipament {id_interventie = 2, tip_interventie="2"},
            new InterventiiCuEchipament {id_interventie = 3, tip_interventie="3"},
        };            
            return _dbCountries;
        }
    }
```

---

```
[ServiceContract]
     public interface IServicePl
     { 
         [OperationContract]
         IEnumerable<InterventiiCuEchipament> GetInterventiiCuEchipaments();            
     }
     [DataContract]
     public class InterventiiCuEchipament
     {
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        public int id_interventie { get; set; }         
        public string tip_interventie { get; set; }
     }
```

**client side**

```
ServicePlClient client = new ServicePlClient();
List<InterventiiCuEchipament> ListaInterventii = new List<InterventiiCuEchipament>(); 
ListaInterventii = client.GetInterventiiCuEchipamentsAsync().Result.ToList();
```

[image]